# PHP: Get Parent Class Property Values

Tags: php, oop

I have an Abstract class that is extended by a child class.

I need to retrieve an array of all the properties and their values for the abstract class, from within a method inside the abstract class.

Is there a simpler way to do this other than this code:

```
$options = get_object_vars($this);
foreach ($options as $var => $value) {
    if (!property_exists(get_class(), $var)) {
        unset($options[$var]);
    }
}
```

`get_object_vars($this)` returns all the properties and their values, but includes the properties of the child class - which I don't want.

Comment: is `get_class_vars(__CLASS__)` an option for you?

Comment: Thanks but this only gets the Property names, not their values

Comment: Well, but if you have the names, you should be able to get their values as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = get_class_vars(get_class());

foreach($options as $key=>$val)
    echo $key . " : " . $val . " => " . $this->$key;
```

This will give an output as

*Propertyname : standardvalue => dynamic value*

Comment: Thanks - but the Abstract class' purpose is to create a WebService connection so I need the dynamic values

Comment: Dynamic values added to the answer